# passing jquery variable to php calling function

Tags: php, jquery

I created a grab url button which get the title of an external url.

For the moment, I type manually the address into the jquery script. And it works fine.

Instead of that, I would like to get the value of an input field where the user can type the url.

The field the user can type the url is simply this

```
<input size="60" maxlength="140" name="Post[url]" id="post_url" type="text" />
```

The field I want to fill is

```
<input size="60" maxlength="140" name="Post[subject]" id="post_subject" type="text" />
```

and the jquery script is the following

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/geturl', array('url' => 'http://bbc.co.uk')); ?>",

        success: function(data) {
                    strang= String(data);
                    $("#post_subject").val(strang);                 
                }   
});
```

Can you tell me how to do this?  I've tried  `$("post_url").val()`   but it does not work.  Variable is apparently not recognized by php.

Comment: Because.. php executes on server, and javascript executes on browser..

Comment: try **echoing your sentence in php** and check what it returns..

Comment: it returns  the title as I expected  BBC - Home Page  in this case @NishantSolanki

Comment: **but you need to pass URL not a title**

Comment: I meant the return value of the php function post/geturl  returns the title of the url I passed as url @NishantSolanki

Comment: try removing `codeigniter functions` just use `echo 'your_url'`..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the offending line of code.

```
url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/geturl', array('url' => 'http://bbc.co.uk')); ?>",
```

Replace with something like:

```
url: 'http://bbc.co.uk'
```

Comment: I gave this code as an example that works.  @Java_user.  I want to replace it by the input field url filled by the user.